# Is factory(3)->make() the same as factory()->count(3)->make()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel, is `factory(3)->make()` the same as `factory()->count(3)->make()`?
They seem to generate the same result.

Comment: If they generate the same result, presumably they are the same? Did you look at the code? I would recommend using the documented methods.

Comment: @miken32 The documentation is using `factory()->count(3)->make()`, so I'm confused why you'd pick the longer version, unless it's because the word `count` better describes what happens. Let me know if anyone knows if there are other differences under the hood.

Comment: I’d use the “longer” version because I’m not in a contest to write the shortest code. I’m writing code that is supported by the library I’m using, and that means not using undocumented method calls.

Comment: You can look “under the hood” yourself to see exactly what the code is doing

Comment: `factory(3)->make()` is less expressive than `factory()->count(3)->make()` if you write the former code and you are part of a team then most likely others in the team will keep bugging you asking what it means while the latter is pretty obvious what it does. Is it worth your time explaining to others just to save a few characters?

Answer (score 1):

The result of passing a number to the **factory() method** or adding the **count() method** to the factory method **is the same**. If you test both on tinker you will get a collection of the model in which you're applying the factory method.

Just keep in mind the factory method can take not only the number of models you want the collection to have, but you can also pass a "state" to your models. In other words, you can modify the properties of the model too:

For example the following command (tested on tinker):

```
User::factory(1, ['name' => 'Ryan'])->make()
```

Will get you the following result:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3547
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#3546
         name: "Ryan",
         email: "nasir20@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2021-10-20 00:13:23",
         #password: "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
         #remember_token: "ww0qiqp9zQ",
       },
     ],
   }
```

the count() method is more clear as some suggested but it only takes one parameter, an integer that specifies the number of models that should be generated.

You can check the API on this link:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.html